# Generating value in json format from database column

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a `column` in `table` with the name `canonicalName` which contains values like `Vision Canada`,`apple computers`. table contains around 10k record. I have to pass these values to an API in the below format. i am using `oracle` database table. table name is `Organization`.

```
{
     "add": [        

        {
            "canonicalName": "Vision Canada"
            
        },
        {
            "canonicalName": "apple computers",                       
        }
    ]
}
```

can you suggest me how can I generate the same in Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what datasource the table is coming from it's hard to give a really specific answer, but here's my best shot in javascript:

```js
const columnName = 'canonicalName' // Get this once from your table
const arrayOfColumnValues = ['Vision Canada', 'Apple Computer'] // However you get your values out of the table they should be in an array like so

// This array will hold all of the { 'canonicalName' : 'x' } fields in the 'Add': [] you need to pass to the API
const arrayOfColumnObjects = []

// Here we iterate through each value from the column in the table and send it to the object array.
// {[columnName]: value} sets the key to the VARIABLE 'columnName'.
// This is different than saying {columnName: value} which would set the key to the STRING "columnName".
arrayOfColumnValues.forEach(value => arrayOfColumnObjects.push({[columnName]: value}))

// Then we wrap the arrayOfColumnObjects in the object we need to send it to the API like so
const apiJsonObject = {
    Add: arrayOfColumnObjects
}

// Of course here you would return it instead of logging
console.log(apiJsonObject)
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9j7xh3L8/)

Comment: Thank you James. Its Oracle database table.

Comment: @ShrutiSharma I know nothing about OracleDB but if you're using Node.js you might give this a try? https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md

Comment: These are not static values James. we will have to read value from database.

Comment: I'm aware, you will need to get a library which can read values from your database similar to the one I linked above. The rest of my code will still work for you as long as you can insert the data from your database in the form of an array. I cannot write you a full implementation because I don't know what library you will use and I don't know the structure of your database. Hopefully my answer has set you in the right direction.